# Hyperlink in Xamarin.Forms Label - index out of range

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, substring

**This works fine if it present only 1 hyperlink, but issue occurs more than one hyperlink are rendered and below issue occured**

> --------- Stack trace --------- at System.String.Substring (System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 length) [0x0004c] in :0 at
>   MPI.UI.Mobile.Converter.HtmlLabelConverter.ProcessString
>   (System.String rawText) [0x0004b] in :0 at
>   MPI.UI.Mobile.Converter.HtmlLabelConverter.Convert (System.Object
>   value, System.Type targetType, System.Object parameter,
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00008] in :0 at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Binding.GetSourceValue (System.Object value, System.Type
>   targetPropertyType) [0x0001b] in <036ea626158e48a4b8dcc52d0593c6a6>:0
>   at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (System.Object
>   sourceObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target,
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Boolean fromTarget)
>   [0x001ce] in <036ea626158e48a4b8dcc52d0593c6a6>:0 at
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (System.Boolean fromTarget)
>   [0x0003e] in <036ea626158e48a4b8dcc52d0593c6a6>:0 at
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.b__49_0 ()
>   [0x00000] in <036ea626158e48a4b8dcc52d0593c6a6>:0 at
>   Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in :0 at
>   Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
>   native__this) [0x00009] in :0 at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object.18(intptr,intptr) -------------------------------
>   --------- Message --------- Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
>   ------------------------------- --------- Source --------- mscorlib ----------

```
public IList<StringSection> ProcessString(string rawText)
{
    const string spanPattern = @"(<a.*?>.*?</a>)";

    MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(rawText, spanPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

    var sections = new List<StringSection>();

    var lastIndex = 0;

    foreach (Match item in collection)
    {
       sections.Add(new StringSection() { Text = rawText.Substring(lastIndex, item.Index) }); <!--Here the issue occurs -->
        lastIndex += item.Index + item.Length;  <!--Here the issue occurs -->

        // Get HTML href 
        var html = new StringSection()
        {
            Link = Regex.Match(item.Value, "(?<=href=\\\")[\\S]+(?=\\\")").Value,
            Text = Regex.Replace(item.Value, "<.*?>", string.Empty)
        };

        sections.Add(html);
    }

    sections.Add(new StringSection() { Text = rawText.Substring(lastIndex) });  <!--Here the issue occurs -->

    return sections;
}

public class StringSection
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to extract URL from string?

Comment: @Anand yes, actually trying to extract URL and text from string

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue, issue from **rawText.Substring**  index out of range..

```
public IList<StringSection> ProcessString(string rawText)
        {
            try
            {
                const string spanPattern = @"(<a.*?>.*?</a>)";

                MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(rawText, spanPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

                var sections = new List<StringSection>();

                int lastIndex = 0;
                int lastLinkIndex = 0;

                foreach (Match item in collection)
                {
                    var foundText = item.Value;
                    var currentIndexText = rawText.Substring(lastIndex, (item.Index - lastIndex));
                    sections.Add(new StringSection() { Text = currentIndexText });
                    lastIndex += item.Index + item.Length;
                    lastLinkIndex = item.Index + item.Length;
                    // Get HTML href 
                    var html = new StringSection()
                    {
                        Link = Regex.Match(item.Value, "(?<=href=\\\")[\\S]+(?=\\\")").Value,
                        Text = Regex.Replace(item.Value, "<.*?>", string.Empty)
                    };

                    sections.Add(html);
                }

                sections.Add(new StringSection() { Text = rawText.Substring(lastLinkIndex) });

                return sections;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Oh great.Glad to know

Answer (score 0):

The [solution posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61659020/3910951) does not work with three or more hyperlinks. With the following version you can use as many hyperlinks in the same text without Substring() throwing an out of range exception.

```
 public IList<StringSection> ProcessString(string rawText)
        {
            const string spanPattern = @"(<a.*?>.*?</a>)";

            MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(rawText, spanPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

            var sections = new List<StringSection>();

            var lastIndex = 0;

            foreach (Match item in collection)
            {
                var foundText = item.Value; 

                int textWithoutHyperlinkLength = item.Index - lastIndex;
                StringSection textWithoutHyperlink = 
                    new StringSection() 
                    { 
                        Text = rawText.Substring(lastIndex, textWithoutHyperlinkLength) 
                    };
                sections.Add(textWithoutHyperlink); 

                
                var htmlHyperlink = new StringSection()
                {
                    Link = Regex.Match(item.Value, "(?<=href=\\\")[\\S]+(?=\\\")").Value,
                    Text = Regex.Replace(item.Value, "<.*?>", string.Empty)
                };

                sections.Add(htmlHyperlink);

                lastIndex = item.Index + item.Length;
            }

            sections.Add(new StringSection() { Text = rawText.Substring(lastIndex) });

            return sections;
        }
```